# Excel Conditional Format Rule in C# - Check whether cells in a different column for a certain value

Tags: c#, excel, conditional-formatting

I want a conditional format rule in column `Y`, which checks whether column `A` of the same row has **No** as the value. 
However there is a mistake in `line 1` of the code, but I don't know what it is exactly.

**That should be the result:**

[image: Conditional Format Rule made in Excel]

**This is my code:**

```
FormatCondition format = (FormatCondition)ws.Cells.Range[Y:Y].FormatConditions.Add(cell["A1"], XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "No");
format.Interior.Color = LIGHT_GREY;
format.Font.Color = GREY;
```

> (Note: GREY and LIGHT_GREY are `readonly` variables which work in other code snippets)

Comment: Well, yes, as far as I can see [you're not invoking `Add` correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add)

Comment: How would it be correct? I know how to do it when you have a conditional format based on a cell value but not how to do it when it's based on an expression like in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the arguments to Add crossed up. I believe it should be the following but I'm not in a position to test it..

```
Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1: "=$A1=\"No\"");
```